# MVC 4 Model not populating dropdowns

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC and have three related classes that should be populating dropdowns after I generate the controllers but they are turning up empty.  The classes are:

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Tag { get; set; }
    public string Operator { get; set; }
    public int YardId { get; set; }
    public virtual Yard Yard { get; set; }
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
    public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
}

public class Yard
{
    public int YardId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
}

public class Status
{
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
}
```

Each vehicle will have a yard and a status that will be selected from a populated dropdown.  After I generate the controllers for Vehicle, Yard and Status I add a Status record and a Yard record but they do not show up for Vehicle in it's dropdowns.  The dropdowns remain empty and I am unsure why.  I tried a similar model and it generated without a problem but I seem to be missing something here.

The code from the VehicleController is below

```
public class VehicleController : Controller   
{
        private VehicleContext db = new VehicleContext();

    //
    // GET: /Vehicle/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var vehicles = db.Vehicles.Include(v => v.Yard).Include(v => v.Status);
        return View(vehicles.ToList());
    }

    //
    // GET: /Vehicle/Details/5

    public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
    {
        Vehicle vehicle = db.Vehicles.Find(id);
        if (vehicle == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(vehicle);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Vehicle/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.YardId = new SelectList(db.Yards, "YardId", "Name");
        ViewBag.StatusId = new SelectList(db.Status, "StatusId", "Name");
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Vehicle/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Vehicle vehicle)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Vehicles.Add(vehicle);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.YardId = new SelectList(db.Yards, "YardId", "Name", vehicle.YardId);
        ViewBag.StatusId = new SelectList(db.Status, "StatusId", "Name", vehicle.StatusId);
        return View(vehicle);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Vehicle/Edit/5

    public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        Vehicle vehicle = db.Vehicles.Find(id);
        if (vehicle == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        ViewBag.YardId = new SelectList(db.Yards, "YardId", "Name", vehicle.YardId);
        ViewBag.StatusId = new SelectList(db.Status, "StatusId", "Name", vehicle.StatusId);
        return View(vehicle);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Vehicle/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Vehicle vehicle)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(vehicle).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.YardId = new SelectList(db.Yards, "YardId", "Name", vehicle.YardId);
        ViewBag.StatusId = new SelectList(db.Status, "StatusId", "Name", vehicle.StatusId);
        return View(vehicle);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Vehicle/Delete/5

    public ActionResult Delete(int id = 0)
    {
        Vehicle vehicle = db.Vehicles.Find(id);
        if (vehicle == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(vehicle);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Vehicle/Delete/5

    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Vehicle vehicle = db.Vehicles.Find(id);
        db.Vehicles.Remove(vehicle);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your razor code/where you are binding the models collections to the  dropdown list.

Comment: Please how you pass model to the view.

Comment: Where would I find the razor code that binds the models collections to the dropdown list?  I let VS generate the code for the controllers so I am not sure where it would be stored.

Comment: Is it what is in the VehicleContoller?

Comment: right-click on the action -> go to view

Comment: I'm not sure of the action you are referring to.  I'm sorry but I am completely new to MVC.

Comment: Interestingly, I used the same classes in MVC 5 and used the same Context Class for all three controllers this time and it just works.  Now I don't know if it is the order I did things, the fact that I used the same context or MVC 5 that resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

using lazy loader you can do this its quite simple

look at passing a drop down list in the vehicle index

your data class/model

```
    public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Status")]
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
```

index contoller

in a logic class you should have a method that returns a list of all statuses
and a class to return a list of  Vehicles

```
  ViewBag.Status = new SelectList(logic.getALLStatus(), "StatusId","Name");
  return View(Vehiclelogic.GetALLVehicles.tolist());
```

then just add the view and let Scaffolding do the rest :)
When you code your logic in a different layer it makes life so much easier and helps with Unit Testing:)